# Are there any "catalysts" that decrease the rate of reaction

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Catalysts are things you can add to a reaction that provide an alternate reaction pathway for the reaction that decreases the overall activation energy of the reaction meaning the reaction is faster but the catalyst isn't consumed in the reactions. Are there any materials, in any reactions where a similar material can be added to a reaction that will decrease the rate of reaction by providing a more favorable reaction pathway but one that takes longer.

Maybe it isn't possible for a reaction to be more favorable but require a higher activation energy and this is why this kind of "pseudo catalyst" doesn't exist.

Comment: We'd probably call such a catalyst an inhibitor, and it probably work by increasing the activation energy instead of decreasing it. Perhaps a mutated enzyme could work, one that still binds its substrate with high affinity, but was not capable of catalysis.

Comment: In an electrochemical cell setting, one can accelerate the electrochemistry by increasing the surface area of the cathode relative to the anode.  It follows that modifying the cell with inert material (less anodic than the current anode and less noble than the existing cathode) that decreases the surface area of the cathode could be an inhibitor. For example, create a partial CuO layer on an existing Cu cathode (aka, poison the cathode).

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, a catalyst can only be a catalyst if it lowers the barrier as that is part of its definition.

Comment: @AJKOER Certainly, but how do you do that?

Comment: The poisoning of 'catalyst' occurs frequently with a vehicle's catalytic converter. In my reference to a Cu cathode, just remove part of it, wash and heated it in air till its glows red (Cu->Cu2O->CuO) inducing a visible alteration in color. Replaces the part and the battery cell performance changes.

Comment: Continuation of my comment: Relatedly, if one is trying to perform an anodic dissolution of say Tungsten metal, in say HOCl (this is a battery cell-based electrosynthesis) with a noble cathode like Pt, using a large surface area Pt mesh is much more efficient.

Comment: @AJKOER If you take the system apart anyway, you might as well cut off half the cathode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, such a "negative catalyst" cannot increase the activation energy of already existing path.

An alternative with the higher activation energy would not be significantly taken. You can detour a river making it flow easier by a side channel, but not if you lead it across a hill.

It could act differently, as an  inhibitor, blocking the low activation energy path by reaction with the key intermediate product or existing catalyst, or by competitive inhibition.

Many redox reactions, including food deterioration, are catalyzed by traces of transient metals acting as redox catalysts, typically copper. An additive, forming metal complexes like EDTA, in large extend inhibits these catalyzed reactions.

Comment: With a pipe, if the hill is less than ten meters? Sorry.  ;-)

Comment: @Karl You would need to suck water up to this 10 m first. BTW, is it still a hill, according to English cartographic terminology ?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly. Let's say your reaction is

$$\ce{D -> E}$$

Your inhibitor could catalyse an additional reaction

$$\ce{C <<=> D}$$

If the equillibrium of that reaction was well on the left side, that would slow down the original reaction quite a bit.

Alternatively, it could catalyse a reaction $\ce{D->B}$, where B had an additional pathway

$$\ce{E <- B <- D -> E}$$

, which might be slow.

This is all however very hypothetical. I cannot name an example for either.

Generally, if you find that something acts as an inhibitor, that means the reaction was already catalysed, and your inhibitor either permanently poisons the catalyst, or reversibly converts it into an inactive form.

Comment: Equilibrium arrows are <=>. <-> are for tautomerization/resonance.

Comment: @Poutnik And you can even give them a bias <<=> <=>>. +1

Comment: sure, I use it often.  See [mhchem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88)

Comment: Karl: +1, your answer seems to incorporate my example of cathodic poisoning in a battery cell (cited in my comment above).